# Radiation-Glossy Black vs Matte White

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation

Well, studying the chapter Heat I know that a matte black body radiates heat more than a glossy white one but can anyone give me an answer about what happens when its a **glossy black** body and a **dull colored white** body?

Answer (score 1):

The spectral radiation rate depends on the material in question and the temperature of the material.  You can start to learn about this by Googling "Black Body Radiation" and "Planck" .  Your terms "glossy black" and "dull white" are far too vague (in a scientific or engineering sense) to be able to answer.  Further, the visual color is not necessarily related to the emissivity in the infrared or other portions of the electromagnetic spectrum.  The spectral emissivity, especially for objects whose temperature is less than roughly 1500 K, is of most interest in the IR band.

Answer (score 0):

Colour will take priority.

For example a shiny black sheet of metal and a matte white... The black will get hotter in the sun.